# create a hatched band

Tags: adobe-photoshop

i am trying to create a hatched band around a shape, for example a circle or s square. in the case of the circle i want this to follow the circle on the inside, and in case of a square to follow the square edges on the inside. any possible way to do this? instead of placing each line one by one.

thanks[image]

Comment: It would be offcourse more appropriate to do this in illustrator.

Comment: If one *must* use Photoshop.. a pattern fill on a custom shape is the best method.

Comment: Hi, i don't know how to use illustrator, but i know a little Photoshop. i will try to look for tutorials on cutom shape fill in PS. thanks